# how to redirect wildcard subdomain to matching directory and run the code?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have many small apps running in subdirectories of my web root. For example I have this file structure:

```
/webroot
    .htaccess
    index.php
        /apps
            /todo
                .htaccess
                index.php
            /calendar
                .htaccess
                index.php
```

Instead of creating a subdomain for each one, I have created a wildcard subdomain. I would like todo.mydomain.com to run the index.php in /webroot/apps/todo and calendar.mydomain.com to run the index.php in /webroot/apps/calendar.

Some of these apps require their own .htaccess, so that, for example, todo.mydomain.com/list/completed would still run /webroot/apps/todo/index.php

Can I do that in .htaccess? I've dug around SO and tried a few examples but they all seem to want to run one index.php in the webroot. How can I run multiple apps without creating each subdomain?

Comment: What are in the other htaccess files?

Comment: Nearly all of them just point all requests to index.php https://gist.github.com/coreymaass/6762389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by the amazing tech support at Wiredtree.com, the best hosting company ever.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+).site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./folder/%2/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try this one this will rewrite the URL to one that includes the subdomain and the original request URI.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/%1/$1 [PT]
```

Comment: Almost there, I think! site.com works. www.site.com works. but going to test.site.com throws an Internal Server Error instead of running /folder/test/index.php. Is there a way to "echo out" the path it's trying to run? I've checked my error log but don't see anything.

Comment: @Corey since there are multiple htaccess files, it's hard to say, but you need to look in your error logs to see what it says caused the error